# Error reading Json Array in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, android-studio

JSON

```
{
"data": [{
    "id": "0bfe9470-4a57-11e8-8594-9fed6c4fe65b",
    "type": 6,
    "order": 12,
    "data": {
        "goto": "+",
        "type": 6,
        "order": 12,
        "options": [{
            "display": "P\u00e9ssimo"
        }, {
            "display": "Ruim"
        }, {
            "display": "Regular"
        }, {
            "display": "Bom"
        }, {
            "display": "\u00d3timo"
        }],
        "required": true,
        "answer": []
    }
}, {
    "id": "0594b030-4a57-11e8-8c83-0d7c6461d799",
    "type": 5,
    "order": 10,
    "data": {
        "type": 5,
        "order": 10,
        "options": {
            "left": {
                "goto": "+",
                "display": 0
            },
            "right": {
                "goto": "+",
                "display": 100
            },
            "center": {
                "goto": "+",
                "display": 50
            }
        },
        "required": true,
        "answer": []
    }
}, {
    "id": "00f8dea0-4a57-11e8-ab0b-7b5c52826681",
    "type": 4,
    "order": 9,
    "data": {
        "type": 4,
        "order": 9,
        "options": [{
            "items": [{
                "goto": "+",
                "display": "Bom"
            }, {
                "goto": "+",
                "display": "Regular"
            }, {
                "goto": "+",
                "display": "Ruim"
            }],
            "display": "Thiago Silva"
        }, {
            "items": [{
                "goto": "+",
                "display": "Bom"
            }, {
                "goto": "+",
                "display": "Regular"
            }, {
                "goto": "+",
                "display": "Ruim"
            }],
            "display": "Thiago Silva"
        }],
        "required": true,
        "answer": []
    }
}]
}
```

CODE - PageReports ADD

```
public class PageReports implements Serializable{

    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private List<Datum> data = null;

    public List<Datum> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<Datum> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}

private void getReportPages(String id) {
    if (subscription != null) {
        subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
    subscription = RxUtil.appleHandlerStartFinish(
            RestBuilder.api().getReportPage(RestParams.authHeaderAccept(getContext()), id),
            () -> base.displayProcess(),
            () -> base.dismissProcess())
            .compose(RxUtil.applySchedulers())
            .subscribe(
                    pageReports -> {
                       // LogUtil.e("JSON: ", SuApp.getInstance().gson().toJson(pageReports));
                        if (pageReports != null && pageReports.getData() != null && pageReports.getData().size() > 0) {
                            currentDataReport.setDataPages(pageReports.getData());
                            viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(pageReports.getData().size());
                            mPagerAdapter = new ReportPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), pageReports.getData());
                            viewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
                            indicator.setViewPager(viewPager);
                        }
                    },
                    throwable -> throwable.printStackTrace()
            );
}

public static Map<String,String> authHeaderAccept(Context context) {
    Map<String, String> header = defaultHeader();
    header.put("Authorization","Bearer " + Preference.getInstance(context).getToken());
    return header;
}
```

ERROR

```
W/System.err: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 125 path $.data[0].data.options
W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:224)
                  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
                  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
                  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
                  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
                  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
                  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
                  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
                  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
                  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
                  at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:39)
                  at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:27)
                  at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.toResponse(ServiceMethod.java:122)
                  at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:217)
W/System.err:     at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:180)
                  at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.CallExecuteOnSubscribe.call(CallExecuteOnSubscribe.java:40)
                  at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.CallExecuteOnSubscribe.call(CallExecuteOnSubscribe.java:24)
                  at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.BodyOnSubscribe.call(BodyOnSubscribe.java:36)
                  at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.BodyOnSubscribe.call(BodyOnSubscribe.java:28)
                  at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10256)
                  at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:100)
                  at rx.internal.schedulers.CachedThreadScheduler$EventLoopWorker$1.call(CachedThreadScheduler.java:230)
                  at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
                  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:269)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
              Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 125 path $.data[0].data.options
W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:385)
                  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:213)
                ... 28 more
```

I'm trying to read but always error, if I have only one value inside the JSON I can do the search, but when it has the 3 it does not.

It's as if GSON () classes were not converting. What could be done on this occasion so that the error does not occur again? Changing JSON or is there an error in the code that I have not yet identified?

Comment: At first glance it looks like you're trying to load JSON directly into an object, and the JSON contains an array at a point that the Java object does not have an array. Can you identify which field is at line 1 column 125 and check that against your Java object definition?

Comment: @Hugg please post your `pageReports` model code

Comment: @Kulebin code add

Comment: That doesn't really tell us anything. As Gewure points out (and I'd missed in the error), the problem is with the 'options' element: the first Datum has this as an array, and the second just an object. Which means we'll need to see the options field, which means the PageReports you've posted that just contains Datum objects means nothing without Datum too, and if the options is in another object that that contains then it would be useful to see that too. But hopefully you have enough now: it sounds like the array in the first Datum in the JSON is wrong. Do you need to accept both array + obj?

Comment: @Rup. Now I understand the error, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second `data` Object is missing `[` and later `]` at `options`:

```
"options": {
        "left": {
            "goto": "+",
```

for whatever reason..

make this

```
"options": [{
            "left": {
                "goto": "+",
```

..and close the Array with the corresponding  ] at the end